# Bash doesn't think string is properly quoted?

Tags: python, bash, ssh, paramiko

I'm attempting to execute a command over SSH, but bash on the other end doesn't think it's escaped properly.

Here, `self._client` is a `paramiko.SSHClient` object; `args` is a list of arguments, the command to execute.

```
def run(self, args, stdin=None, capture_stdout=False):
    """Runs a command.

    On success, returns the output, if requested, or None.

    On failure, raises CommandError, with stderr and, if captured, stdout,
    as well as the exit code.
    """
    command = ' '.join(_shell_escape(arg) for arg in args)
    print('About to run command:\n  {}'.format(command))
    print('About to run command:\n  {!r}'.format(command))
    channel = self._client.get_transport().open_session()
    channel.exec_command(command)
```

`_shell_escape`:

```
_SHELL_SAFE = _re.compile(r'^[-A-Za-z0-9_./]+$')
def _shell_escape(s):
    if _SHELL_SAFE.match(s):
        return s
    return '\'{}\''.format(s.replace('\'', '\'\\\'\''))
```

I'm attempt to run some Python through this. On `stderr`, I get back:

```
bash: -c: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The output from the two print statements:

```
About to run command:
  python -c 'import os, sys
path = sys.argv[1]
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    path = path.decode('\''utf-8'\'')
entries = os.listdir(path)
out = b'\'''\''.join(e.encode('\''utf-8'\'') + b'\'''\'' for e in entries)
sys.stdout.write(out)
' .
About to run command:
  "python -c 'import os, sys\npath = sys.argv[1]\nif sys.version_info.major == 2:\n    path = path.decode('\\''utf-8'\\'')\nentries = os.listdir(path)\nout = b'\\'''\\''.join(e.encode('\\''utf-8'\\'') + b'\\''\x00'\\'' for e in entries)\nsys.stdout.write(out)\n' ."
```

If I copy and paste the output of `command`, and paste it into `bash`, it executes, so it really does appear to be properly escaped. My current understanding is that SSH, on the other end, will take command, and run `[my_shell, '-c', command]`.

**Why is `bash` erroring on that command?**

Comment: Have you considered using [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) (Python 3.x) or [`pipes.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) (Python 2.x) instead of rolling your own?

Comment: (Not saying you're doing it wrong, I haven't looked at your code closely yet. But I'd probably give those a try first before handling escaping and quoting myself).

Comment: nice question, but consider adding a sanitized version of the command you 'copy(ied) and paste(d) the output of `command`, and paste(d) it into `bash`, it executes'. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: I'm not sure what you're asking for. What I copy/pasted into bash is in the question. (The bit under "About to run command", which is the output of `command`.)

Comment: @LukasGraf: That function is remarkably similar. I'll be adding that, yes. (I gave it a quick test, and sadly, it does not fix the error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The input contains an embedded nul character**, which bash appears to treat as the end of the string. (I'm not sure there's any way it couldn't!). This is visible in my question, where I output `command`:

```
About to run command:
  "python -c 'import os, sys [SNIP…] + b'\\''\x00'\\'' for [SNIP…]"
```

That's a `repr` output, but notice the single slash before the `x` in `\x00`: that's an actual `\x00` that made it through. My original code has this Python embedded as a snippet, which I didn't include (I didn't believe it was relevant):

```
_LS_CODE = """\
import os, sys
path = sys.argv[1]
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    path = path.decode('utf-8')
entries = os.listdir(path)
out = b''.join(e.encode('utf-8') + b'\x00' for e in entries)
sys.stdout.write(out)
"""
```

Here, Python's `"""` is still processing `\` as an escape character. I need to double up, or look into raw strings (`r"""`)

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape newlines as well. A better option is to put the program text in a here document.

Make the output of "About to run command:" to look like

```
python -c << EOF
import os, sys
path = sys.argv[1]
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    path = path.decode('\''utf-8'\'')
entries = os.listdir(path)
out = b'\'''\''.join(e.encode('\''utf-8'\'') + b'\'''\'' for e in entries)
sys.stdout.write(out)
.
EOF
```

Maybe you wouldn't need to escape anything at all.

Comment: Mind adding why? (And how?) The general interface of the function is just to run a command; it just happens that a python command exposed the bug.

Comment: bash is line oriented. An unescaped newline terminates the command. The very first line of your data contains an unmatched tick, which is an error from the bash point of view. See post updated.

Comment: @user58697 How do you figure? Unescaped line feeds in single quoted strings work fine in both scripts and interactive terminals.

Comment: In addition to what "that other guy" mentioned, this function needs to be able to execute arbitrary commands, so heredocs aren't always going to work: your answer focuses too much on the specific example that exposes some bug, and works around the bug instead of fixing it.

Comment: I removed all newlines from the input with a `command = commnad.replace('\n', ' ')`; bash still gives a similar error. (The line number changes, of course, but otherwise it's the same.)